# replacing a for loop with map?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'd like to replace the following for-loop ...

```
data <- data.frame(x = c(2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 6, 9, 10),
                   y = rep(0, 15))
for (i in 2:length(data$x)) {
  data$y[i] <- ifelse(data$x[i] > data$y[i-1], data$y[i-1] + 2, data$y[i-1] - 1)
}
data$y # 0  2  4  3  5  7  6  5  7  9  8  7  6  8 10
```

... and I want to use dplyr and tried the following:

```
data %>%
  mutate(y = if_else(x > lag(y), lag(y) + 2, lag(y) -1 ))
```

But obviously I didn't succeed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that `ifelse` or `if_else` or `case_when` don't help here. The for loop is going step-by-step through the data and calculates each y on the basis of the previous y. My guess was to use `map`.

Comment: What you want to look into is `Reduce` with the argument `accumulate` set to `TRUE`

Comment: Thanks, sounds promising, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `accumulate` from `purrr` package for sequential operations:

```
data %>% 
  mutate( y = accumulate( .x = x[-1],
                          .init = 0,
                          .f = function(y,x) if_else(x > y, y + 2, y - 1) ) 
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you are also interested in a *base* solution using `Reduce` as already suggested by @Sotos in the comments:

```
data$y <- Reduce(function(y,x) ifelse(x > y, y+2, y-1)
                 , data$x[-1], data$y[1], accumulate = TRUE)
data$y
# [1]  0  2  4  3  5  7  6  5  7  9  8  7  6  8 10
```

or

```
data$y <- Reduce(function(y,x) if(x > y) y+2 else y-1
                 , data$x[-1], data$y[1], accumulate = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice to have both!